# replace value under column in pandas under condition

Tags: pandas

I want to replace values under column Severity with following values.
4:out for season
3:out indefinitely
2:DNP
1:DTD
but .replace doesn't seem to work. Any other ways to get around this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRGii.png)

Comment: What code are you using to do the replacement? Also please do post your data itself, and not a picture of it.

Comment: I am using python, and sorry will do next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have things reversed in your replacement code.

Try this out and report back what happens:

```
replace_dict = {'DTD':1,'DNP':2,'out indefinitely':3,'out for season':4}
df = pd.DataFrame({'severity':'out for season'},index=[0])
df['severity'] = df['severity'].replace(replace_dict)
```

Comment: it returns index 0 severity 4

Comment: Is that the behaviour you were after?

Comment: How would I go about  broadcasting the changed value to the entire column? Ex) All the element under column Severity that has a string (DTD) is replaced to 1. (DNP) as 2. and so on

Comment: You're welcome. Please see edited answer with all replacements you have mentioned.

Comment: I assume tweaking the index is the way to go but how do I iterate through it? For loop?

Comment: You shouldn't need to tweak the index.

Comment: because the original code returns only one cell  (index=0)

Comment: Use the last line of the code I posted on *your* DataFrame.